# Modules over ring of polynomials in several indeterminates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I read this proposition and its proof in the Dummit's book (It's not exactly like this, but this is the idea of the proposition).

> Let $F$ be a field, $V$ a vector space over $F[x]$ and $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Then $V$ can be seen as a $F[x]-$module defining 
>   $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\right)\cdot v=\sum_{i=0}^na_i T^i(v)$$
>   (Let's call this extension for now $V(F[x],T)$)
>   Furthermore, every module $M$ over $F[x]$ is a vector space over $F$, the transformation $T(v)=x\cdot v$ is a linear mapping of $M$ and, as a module, $M=M(F[x],T)$

This characterizes all the modules over $F[x]$ as vector spaces over $F$ with a linear mapping on them.

Is there any analogous result for modules over $F[x_1,\cdots,x_r]$?

Comment: The key fact about $F[x]$ is that it is a PID, not so for $F[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: Oh. Then is it required for $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ to be a PID, to be extended that way? 

Couldn't there be some kind of  similar result which only requires it to be Noetherian (Perhaps with another, harder proof)?

Comment: Note that the ring in multiple variables is **never** a PID.

Comment: I know that, that's why I'm asking, Would it be necessary for $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ to be a PID (Which is false), to be extended that way? Isn't there any similar result (It seems that there isn't) like "If $D$ is a noetherian integrl domain, then the modules over $D[x]$ all are determined by it's module structure over $D$ "with something else" "?

Comment: @AdamHughes Maybe I'm being dense, but what does being a PID have to do with anything? The question seems entirely reasonable to me, and egreg's answer is exactly how I would have answered it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman just that the same characterization does not work. The op evidently was happy with a different characterization, but that wasn't evident when I was reading it.

Comment: The two characterizations are analogous. The first one does not use that $F[x]$ is a PID (Am I mistaken?), so we can take $F=R$ be any commutative ring, to characterize the $R[x]-$modules. Then by induction we can characterize all $R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]-$módules as $R-$modules with a $R-$endomorphism, a $R[x_1]-$endomorphism, a $R[x_1,x_2]-$end...

And then prove that a $R[x]-$endomorphism is just a $R-$endomorphism which commutes with $T(m)=x\cdot m$. By induction again and letting $R$ be a field again, we get to the characterization given by egreg. Without using any sophisitcated result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a structure of module over $F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ on $V$ (assuming the action of $F$ is preserved) is the same as specifying an $F$-algebra homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon F[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to \operatorname{End}_F(V)
$$
(the codomain is the ring of $F$-endomorphisms of $V$). This is equivalent to specifying endomorphisms $T_1,\dots, T_n$ that are *pairwise commuting*, that is
$$
T_i\circ T_j=T_j\circ T_i,\qquad 1\le i\le n,\quad 1\le j\le n
$$

If $\varphi$ is given, define $T_i=\varphi(x_i)$; if the commuting endomorphisms are given, use the universal property of polynomial rings, together with the fact that the $F$-subalgebra of $\operatorname{End}_F(V)$ generated by $T_1,\dots,T_n$ is commutative.

Comment: I'll look into it seems I'll have to study it a bit the steps in-between and then see what's the result to arrive to, but it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper The fact $F$ is a field is not used; any commutative ring will do.